# how to predict using html video tag instead of webcam in tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, rtsp, tensorflow.js, teachable-machine

please help, i have rtsp video embbed to html using vlc plugin, the rtsp video setup in html video tag.
the question is in teachable machine, the given code is predict the model using webcam, how can i predict it using rtsp in html video tag instead of using webcam

i have tried to change the webcame setup to document.getelementbyid('video') but it doesnt work

im new in javascript

this is the code from teachable machine, this code predict using webcam

```
<div>Teachable Machine Image Model</div>
<video src="http://localhost:8080" autoplay width="700px" id="video"></video> <!-- this rtsp video emmbed using vlc -->
<button type="button" onclick="init()">Start</button>
<div id="webcam-container"></div>
<div id="label-container"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@teachablemachine/image@latest/dist/teachablemachine-image.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // More API functions here:
    // https://github.com/googlecreativelab/teachablemachine-community/tree/master/libraries/image

    // the link to your model provided by Teachable Machine export panel
    const URL = "https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/models/gUXAFqBw8/";

    let model, webcam, labelContainer, maxPredictions;

    // Load the image model and setup the webcam
    async function init() {
        const modelURL = URL + "model.json";
        const metadataURL = URL + "metadata.json";

        // load the model and metadata
        // Refer to tmImage.loadFromFiles() in the API to support files from a file picker
        // or files from your local hard drive
        // Note: the pose library adds "tmImage" object to your window (window.tmImage)
        model = await tmImage.load(modelURL, metadataURL);
        maxPredictions = model.getTotalClasses();

        // Convenience function to setup a webcam
        const flip = true; // whether to flip the webcam
        webcam = new tmImage.Webcam(200,200, flip); // width, height, flip
        await webcam.setup(); // request access to the webcam
        await webcam.play();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

        // append elements to the DOM
        document.getElementById("webcam-container").appendChild(webcam.canvas);
        labelContainer = document.getElementById("label-container");
        for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) { // and class labels
            labelContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
        }
    }

    async function loop() {
        webcam.update(); // update the webcam frame
        await predict();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }

    // run the webcam image through the image model
    async function predict() {
        // predict can take in an image, video or canvas html element
        const prediction = await model.predict(webcam.canvas);
        for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) {
            const classPrediction =
                prediction[i].className + ": " + prediction[i].probability.toFixed(2);
            labelContainer.childNodes[i].innerHTML = classPrediction;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Thank you in advance